# keep a div previously hidden by jquery open on reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have two divs. One acts as a chat window launcher. Chat window element is hidden by default. When I click the chat window launcher element, chat window appears and launcher hides. I've also made a small close button for the chat window that reverses the operation.

The problem is that when I reload the page, the chat window disappears and I have to relaunch again. What can I do, so that once the launcher is activated, the chat window remains visible even on page reload so that I can only close it using its close button?

HTML

```
<div class="chat-launcher" title="Launch Chat Window">
    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-pencil chat-launcher-pencil " style="color: #ffffff;font-size: 20px;"></span>
</div>
<div class="chat-window ">
    <span id="close">X</span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.chat-launcher').on('click', function () {
            $('.chat-window').show();
            $('.chat-launcher').hide();
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#close').on('click',function(){
            $('.chat-window').hide();
            $('.chat-launcher').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: store it's state in localStorage , or server side session, or cookie and when page loads check that state and react accorrdingly

Comment: You may use the server side session or cookies to track the window is open or close. Better to send some ajax notification to the server with a session id.

Comment: Are you using a `history.back()` operation, by pressing the back button on the Browser? The page should load the same as it always does, unless you are doing an AJAX query or using a session or cookie. To prevent the page from caching you can use `onunload = function(){}` on the page you don't want to change, exactly like that, and when the Client hits the back button you will not get a cached state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a persistent storage in order to save the chat window's state; like server-side sessions, client-side cookies or localStorage.

Utilizing [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage), it will be something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chat-launcher').on('click', function () {
        $('.chat-window').show();
        $('.chat-launcher').hide();

        // Set a flag indicating that the char window is open
        localStorage.setItem('chatWindowOpen', true);
    });

    $('#close').on('click',function(){
        $('.chat-window').hide();
        $('.chat-launcher').show();

        // Remove the flag
        localStorage.removeItem('chatWindowOpen');
    });

    // Open chat window if the flag is there
    if (localStorage.getItem('chatWindowOpen')) {
        $('.chat-launcher').trigger('click');    
    }        
});
```

One other note; As you might have noticed, you don't need multiple `$(document).ready()` calls. One will do for all.